# Acumatica - Make field required based on value of another field

Tags: acumatica

To start I will say I'm working with the Service Management Module in Acumatica on version 6.1. This means that Service Management is a project and not standard at this point in time. I am trying to make a custom Usr field required in a tab on the Service Orders screen based on the value of another custom Usr field. I have tried both `RowUpdated` and `FieldUpdated` events. I have included the code for both below with corresponding errors on both.

Field Updated:

```
protected void FSServiceOrder_Usrwarrstat_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)
    {
      if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
        InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
      var row = (FSServiceOrder)e.Row;
      if(row == null) return;
      var WarrantyStatus = row.Usrwarrstat;
      if (WarrantyStatus == null) return;
      if (WarrantyStatus == "W" || WarrantyStatus == "P"){
        PXDefaultAttribute.SetPersistingCheck<FSServiceOrderExt.usrTransModelNbr>(cache, e, PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank);
      }

    }
```

Error:

```
\App_RuntimeCode\ServiceOrderEntry.cs(484): error CS1061: 'FieldService.ServiceDispatch.FSServiceOrder' does not contain a definition for 'Usrwarrstat' and no extension method 'Usrwarrstat' accepting a first argument of type 'FieldService.ServiceDispatch.FSServiceOrder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Row Updated:

```
protected void FSServiceOrder_RowUpdated(PXCache cache, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
                {

                    var row = (FSServiceOrder)e.Row;
                    var WarrantyStatus = Base.Caches[typeof(FSServiceOrder)].Current.Usrwarrstat;
                    if(row == null) return;
                    if (WarrantyStatus == null) return;
                    if (WarrantyStatus == "W" || WarrantyStatus == "P"){
                    PXDefaultAttribute.SetPersistingCheck<FSServiceOrderExt.usrTransModelNbr>(cache, e, PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank);
                    }

                }
```

Error:

```
\App_RuntimeCode\ServiceOrderEntry.cs(377): error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Usrwarrstat' and no extension method 'Usrwarrstat' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I feel like this has something to do with the Service Management at this time is not a standard in Acumatica during this version so making the cusotm fields won't bind it to the correct view, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a field required based on a condition without writing any event-handlers by using the `PXUIRequired` attribute. You would have to apply this attribute to the `usrTransModelNbr` field (at DAC level):

```
[PXUIRequired(typeof(Where<usrwarrstat, Equal<warrantyW>, Or<usrwarrstat, Equal<warrantyP>>>))]
```

Please note that you need actual BQL constants defined for your "W" and "P" values; I don't know their meaning and just gave them a dummy name. BQL constants need to be defined like that:

```
    public class warrantyW : Constant<string>
    {
        public warrantyW()
            : base("W")
        {
        }
    }
```

The BQL constants can be defined anywhere, but I would recommend placing them with a custom version of your `PXStringListAttribute` for usrwarrstat (that defines which values are available for selection in this dropdown). Here's an example from PX.Objects; you would decorate your field with `[TaxAdjustmentType.List]` in this example instead of `[PXStringList(...)]`

```
public class TaxAdjustmentType
{
    public class ListAttribute : PXStringListAttribute
    {
        public ListAttribute()
            : base(
            new string[] { AdjustOutput, AdjustInput },
            new string[] { Messages.AdjustOutput, Messages.AdjustInput }) { }
    }

    public const string AdjustOutput = "INT";
    public const string AdjustInput = "RET";
    public const string InputVAT = "VTI";
    public const string OutputVAT = "VTO";
    public const string ReverseInputVAT = "REI";
    public const string ReverseOutputVAT = "REO";

    public class adjustOutput : Constant<string>
    {
        public adjustOutput() : base(AdjustOutput) { ;}
    }

    public class adjustInput : Constant<string>
    {
        public adjustInput() : base(AdjustInput) { ;}
    }

    public class inputVAT : Constant<string>
    {
        public inputVAT() : base(InputVAT) { ;}
    }

    public class outputVAT : Constant<string>
    {
        public outputVAT() : base(OutputVAT) { ;}
    }

    public class reverseInputVAT : Constant<string>
    {
        public reverseInputVAT() : base(ReverseInputVAT) { ;}
    }

    public class reverseOutputVAT : Constant<string>
    {
        public reverseOutputVAT() : base(ReverseOutputVAT) { ;}
    }
}
```

You can read more about this attribute and other related attributes such as `PXUIEnabled`, `PXUIVerify` at http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/11/pxuienabled-and-pxuirequired-attributes.html

Comment: This is a good note, will the public class be defined in the DAC or the Graph?

Comment: @Dane it can be placed inside the DAC class, but the right approach in my opinion is within a custom version of PXStringListAttribute that would also hold the different values.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a sample PXStringListAttribute class

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you are trying to access the custom field from the `DAC` instead of accessing it from the `CacheExtension`. I suggest you to do that in the `RowSelected` Event Handler like below:

```
protected void FSServiceOrder_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e,PXRowSelected baseMethod)
{
    if(baseMethod!=null)       //
        baseMethod(sender,e);  // this is equal to this line    baseMethod?.Invoke(sender,e);
    if(e.Row == null) return;
    FSServiceOrder row = (FSServiceOrder)e.Row;

    FSServiceOrderExt rowExt = PXCache<FSServiceOrder>.GetExtension<FSServiceOrderExt>(row);
    if(rowExt!=null)
    {
        if (rowExt.Usrwarrstat == null) 
            return;
        if (rowExt.Usrwarrstat == "W" || rowExt.Usrwarrstat == "P"){
            PXDefaultAttribute.SetPersistingCheck<FSServiceOrderExt.usrTransModelNbr>(cache, e, PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: \App_RuntimeCode\ServiceOrderEntry.cs(375): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '.'
\App_RuntimeCode\ServiceOrderEntry.cs(375): error CS1003: Syntax error, ':' expected
\App_RuntimeCode\ServiceOrderEntry.cs(375): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '.' Which this corresponds to the baseMethod?.Invoke(sender,e); line

Comment: Using this method I have received this error:  'PX.Data.PXRowSelectedEventArgs' to type 'FieldService.ServiceDispatch.FSServiceOrder'. on the screen itself once I change the Usrwarrstat field.

Comment: @Dane check your code, seems like instead of `FSServiceOrder row = (FSServiceOrder)e.Row;` you have written `FSServiceOrder row = (FSServiceOrder)e;`